# Shouldn't intensity increase the stopping voltage in the photoelectric effect?

Tags: electrons, voltage, photoelectric-effect

More intensity means more number of electrons so more probability of there being energetic electrons reaching the collecting plate so the stopping potential should technically be more. But all the explanations say that intensity is independent of stopping potential. What is the reasoning behind this?

I heard that some photoelectrons do actually reach the collecting plate -- the ones that are unusually more energetic than others.

Answer (score 1):

The energy of a photo-electron is a function of the energy of the photon that released it from the surface of the metal.  The energy of the photon depends on its frequency (aka color).

Intensity of a light beam tells you how many photons per second are leaving the source.  For a more intense light beam on a metal surface, more electrons are liberated from the surface, but the energy of those electrons does not increase with light intensity - only their number do.  This means that the light source intensity does NOT increase the stopping voltage of the liberated electrons, but it does result in more electrons being stopped.

Answer (score 0):

The intensity of the light has no effect on the maximum kinetic energy of the photoelectrons. Therefore, the stopping voltage does not increase.

Comment: It's important to mention that you're assuming multi-photon effects are negligible.

Comment: Yeah I know that, but there are some electrons that reach the collector screen regardless of the intensity of light because they have unusually more energy than normal, is this true?

Comment: The stopping voltage is that needed to stop *the most energetic electrons* that are emitted from reaching the anode. This maximum energy is linearly related to the frequency of the light, but independent of the light intensity.